# Calling Java method in trigger after insert in Java Derby

Tags: java, stored-procedures, derby, triggers

I had a method in Java like this:

```
public static void extract(int id, String title, String description) throws SQLException{
    // doing some Java here
}
```

then successfully created a procedure from above Java method

```
CREATE PROCEDURE extract_keyword(IN id INTEGER, IN title VARCHAR(255), IN description VARCHAR(255))
LANGUAGE JAVA
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
EXTERNAL NAME 'com.example.Test.extract';
```

but when I tried to create a trigger to call this procedure after insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER "extract_keyword_trigger"
AFTER INSERT
ON "ARTICLE"
FOR EACH ROW
CALL "extract_keyword" (NEW."id", NEW."title", NEW."description");
```

where, ARTICLE is the table name with 3 columns: id, title, description.

Above command gave me error:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X15: Column name 'id' appears in a statement without a FROM list.
```

What should be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [referencing clause](https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/ref/rrefsqlj89752.html#rrefsqlj89752) as described in the [CREATE TRIGGER section of the Derby Reference Manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj43125.html)

Comment: I think that is optional